# How to get all rows from mysqli result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
$query = "select * from users order by ID";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
// Associative array
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["email"], $row["password"]);
mysqli_close($db);
```

My problem is that this code always prints only one user's details, but there are actually three users in the database. I would like to display all of the records. How can I fetch all of the results from MySQLi?

Comment: Time to learn about loops

Comment: You need to loop through your result in order to print more than 1 record.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed `while()` that's why you are getting the single result. You can learn more about loops [here](https://www.guru99.com/php-loop.html)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["email"] . $row["password"];
}
```

For making your code more efficient and secure you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [prepared staments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: $query = "select * from users where username='$_SESSION['username']"; is this correct if i want to display detail with my current session

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it

Comment: Better to store `$_SESSION['username']` into a variable then put that variable in your query

Comment: `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`

Comment: how about this $query = "select * from users where username=".$name; in above i added $name= $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: `$query = "select * from users where username='$username'";`

Comment: You don't need to concatenate it.

Comment: Nice. Kindly accept my answer if it really helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
$query = "select * from users order by ID";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<pre>";
printf ("Email: %s  password: %s", $row["email"], $row["password"]);
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```